# Como exportar varios componentes por defecto?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, ecmascript-6, styled-components

Tengo 2 componentes que deseo exportar para usarlos en otro componente. Hay alguna manera de exportarlos a todos por defecto ?
Intente haciendo : `export default { NoteContainer, NoteHeader };` `export default * ;`
pero no funcionó.

```
import styled from 'styled-components';

const NoteContainer = styled.div`
  textarea {
    background-color: var(--color-white);
    border: none;
    padding: 16px 12px;
    width: 100%;
    height: 70vh;
    resize: none;
    scrollbar-width: none; /* Firefox */

    &::active,
    &::focus {
      outline: none;
      border: none;
    }

    ::-webkit-scrollbar {
      display: none;
    }
  }
`;

const NoteHeader = styled.div`
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: space-between;
  color: var(--color-main);
  padding: 10px;
`;

export default { NoteContainer, NoteHeader };
```

Answer (score 1):

No puedes utilizar `export default` si vas a exportar dos valores, de [la documentación](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/web/javascript/reference/statements/export):

> Si queremos exportar **UN SÓLO** valor o tener uno por defecto para
> nuestro módulo, podemos usar un export por defecto:

Te recomiendo que lo hagas por medio de exports simples:

```
import styled from 'styled-components';

export const NoteContainer = styled.div`
  textarea {
    background-color: var(--color-white);
    border: none;
    padding: 16px 12px;
    width: 100%;
    height: 70vh;
    resize: none;
    scrollbar-width: none; /* Firefox */

    &::active,
    &::focus {
      outline: none;
      border: none;
    }

    ::-webkit-scrollbar {
      display: none;
    }
  }
`;

export const NoteHeader = styled.div`
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: space-between;
  color: var(--color-main);
  padding: 10px;
`;
```

Luego en donde lo necesites puedes hacer algo como:

```
import {NoteContainer, NoteHeader} from "./modulo"
```